# Comparing elements of two vectors of objects

Tags: c++, class, vector, iterator

I have two vectors of objects each containing information of prices

```
std::vector<OrderInformation> v_SellOrders;

std::vector<OrderInformation> v_BuyOrders;
```

I want to compare one particular price value of v_SellOrders to all the price values of v_BuyOrders, and see if it is smaller than the maximum value of all of them.  And then return an iterator to the first value in v_BuyOrders that it is smaller than.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be better if v_BuyOrders is sorted. Maybe the best way for that is use std::set instead of std::vector. For that you have to define operator<(const OrderInformation&, const OrderInformation) or any function doing the comparison you can give to the constructor of std::set.
After that, it will be easy to do what you want with `std::set::lower_bound`

Comment: Is there any way to do it as a vector as I've used them in many other places in my code?

Comment: Of course yes. So, the best way is to use a sorted vector. For example, previously sorted with `std::sort` in `<algorithm>`. And then, use `std::lower_bound` on the sorted vector. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You're looking for a *partition*. Here's some code (untested, I'm afraid):

```
#include <algorithm>

struct PriceIsMoreThan
{
  const OrderInformation &valueToCheck;

  PriceIsMoreThan(const OrderInformation& value) : valueToCheck(value) {}
  bool operator()(const OrderInformation& other)
  {
    return other.price > valueToCheck.price;
  }
};

OrderInformation& valueToCheck = v_SellOrders[index];
auto firstBiggerIterator = std::partition(v_BuyOrders.begin(), v_BuyOrders.end(), PriceIsMoreThan(valueToCheck));

if (firstBiggerIterator == v_BuyOrders.end())
{
  // Price is greater than all in v_BuyOrders
}
else
{
  // firstBiggerIterator points to first element in v_BuyOrders that is bigger than your search price.
}
```

Note that this will re-order `v_BuyOrders`. See the [documentation on `partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition).

Comment: Thanks so much...I probably should've mentioned that they were vectors of objects though!

Comment: @RuthO'Brien: That shouldn't matter. You'll see that the predicate in my code - `PriceIsMoreThan` - compares the `price` members of two objects. Adjust it to your particular case.